# Add users to a server folder

Tags: windows-server-2003, shell, user-management, directory

I use Windows Server 2003 R2. I am logged in as user Administrator.
I want to give myself permission to add a user for a certain folder. I granted myself all possible permissions for the parent folder of this folder. But it is still not possible to add users in the sub folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Domain Controller, go look in the USERS that have access to the folder, and Create a new users in this group.

If you don't use DC, then directly create user, and add him to the groups that own the folder and subfolder. Use the right permission on the user and enjoy.

Hope this will help you.